# How to cut a single clip in a Sequence into multiple clips for use in multiple Sequences in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, editing, post-production, cs6

I have a single clip of a multi-speaker conference in Premiere Pro CS6 that I need to split into individual clips of each speaker, so that I can make a timeline of each clip with the end goal of exporting several individual videos, rather than one long video of the entire conference.

I've already split the clip up within a Sequence using the Razor Tool and removed extraneous footage, like so:

[image: razor at work]

How can I get these split-up and renamed clips to their own individual Sequences for production as separate video files? (If there is a Premiere shortcut or tool specifically for this, I haven't found it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to simply click the New Item button at the bottom-right of the Project window and select "Sequence..." to create a new one; you'll need one Sequence for each clip section you've created:

[image: New item location]

From there, You can simply copy/cut and paste each section of video into its respective Sequence. You'll want to make sure the old sections are removed from the original Sequence if you want to use that one. Otherwise, you can just delete the original Sequence when you're finished.

---

You could copy each section into your Project Window by dragging and dropping it, but that creates two extra steps (and can be confusing if you haven't already renamed your split-up files in the original sequence):

- The new file in the Project Window won't be aware that you've renamed it in the timeline, so you'll have to rename the new clip; it'll have the same name as the original source clip, *even if* you rename the original source clip to something else.
- You'd still have to create new Sequences for each clip manually, so that you can drag and drop the new clips into their own respective Sequences.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the "Premiere" way to do it.  Create N sequences, one for each of the N speakers you want to create an output clip for.  Copy (by reference) the clip into each of the N sequences.  If you do this correctly, you will have N sequences and 1 clip in your project folder.

For each sequence, set the in and out points of the clip to bound the speaker of interest.  Name the sequence according to the speaker.  If you do this correctly, you will still have N sequences and 1 clip in your project folder.

Here's the magic: select all the sequences and hit "Export Media".  This will queue up the creation of N clips.  Each one will be exactly the speaker it should be, and the clip file names will be based on the sequence name (meaning something related to each speaker).

That is how to do it.

Comment: If I select multiple Sequences in the Project Window, the "Media..." option in the Export sub-menu is grayed out. Only AAF and Final Cut Pro are selectable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to NEST each clip. Select the Video portion and Audio portion together. Right click with your mouse and select "Nest...". Rename to desired sequence name (Remember to copy this name and use for every new Nest you create, so you can have the sequence name be same, like, CUT_01, CUT_02, etc..). Then, once finished, create a new bin in project and organize all cuts there. Not only is this the fastest way to do this, but also helps you keep all Nested Sequences in the same timeline. This will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheesy workaround that I use sometimes. You can set the start and end points (in & out?) to encompass just a single clip, and then export it. Then move the start and end points to encompass the next clip, and export that. You will end up with a separate video for each of the clips, but you won't have a Premiere file that you could easily use to produce them again, since they'll all still be in the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Another cheesy solution, which will create one Premiere file for each of the clips:

- Exit out of Premiere.
- Duplicate your Premiere file once for each clip in it.  (Ten clips? Ten Premiere files.)
- Open up each Premiere file, one at a time. In the first Premiere file, keep the first clip and delete all the others. Save it. In the second Premiere file, keep the select clip and delete all the others.  And so on.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have one clip already cut up inside a single sequence, the easiest workaround is probably to make several copies of your current sequence. Within each new sequence, delete all the extra pieces, so that each sequence ends up as just one separate portion of the original clip.

Comment: This solution is already given in the accepted answer.

Comment: @TylerH The accepted answer is to create new sequences and then copy the video clip into those sequences. This answer is to copy the existing sequence and then remove the unnecessary clips from each sequence (which is a copy of the original).

Comment: I don't see a substantial difference in methodology there. This answer is like the difference between tying your shoes starting with the left shoe vs starting with the right. All the other answers describe substantially different methods (use self-lacing shoes; use shoes without shoelaces; use the bunny method instead of the bow method; etc).